# How to update multiple tables in db with a single click of a button in view in Rubyonrails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have 3 models for a module.In view, I have fetched the values and display those values in a table format in view. Now, if I edited values in the table and on clicking save button, the corresponding values should be updated in the respective tables in db and return back to the same view with same id.How can I accomplish this?

If I added a row and corresponding values in a table in view, those values should also be added in their respective tables.

```
<table>
<%@task.each do |task|%>
<tr id="task-<%=task.id%>">
<td>task.name</td>
</tr>
<%@subtask.each do |subtask|%>
<tr id="subtask-<%=subtask.id%>">
....
</tr>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Now on clicking save button, subtask model should be updated with subtasks and task model should be updated with task. Subtask model references Task model and Task model references invoice model. While fetching values invoice id is the base and based on that tasks and subtasks are being fetched.

I want to update values in the models based on Invoice_ID. I dont want to redirect because I should be in the same view and the data should be updated in db.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing model , view, controller concept. 
If you want to edit something in through view and want to change database then you have to use some kind of form in your view in which you can edit values and correspondingly you must have a method in your controller to handle that post request.
And in your controller you have to save those values in tables. 
for example here is the view that will take input

```
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="gravatar_edit">
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails">change</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ANd its corresponding controller is Users Controller :

```
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

 def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                 :password_confirmation)
  end
```

where name, email , password are table fields in database

Comment: I have used all the above. I have a form that posts values and the data gets saved in the database. Now I have another form which fetches values from 3 tables in db and displays it. It also has editing options. Now when i click save button, the data should be updated in the respective tables in db, and the same view should be persisted without redirecting.

Comment: Can you share more details, your controller details , what you are getting in params[] hash ??